# Javascript error: Out of memory or 'Telerik' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am getting following JavaScript  error frequently on production server. This stops page to work.  On our production server 100 employs using web application simultaneously. may be this cause issue, I don’t know.  The main problem is that I had never get this error on my local server and  not able to reproduce issue on production server.

Is any one know cause of this JavaScript error 'out of memory' issue?

The error

> javascript: out of memory

produces

> Telerik is undefined

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MDDC; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Timestamp: Fri, 26 Apr 2013 18:22:09 UTC

Message: Out of memory
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://DSM/Journal.aspx?AppId=379818&ClaimID=46944&IwID=48914&ClaimNo=0271068974&IwName=Angel Berrios&AppNo=380844&Screen=Appointment&hideTop=hide&ActId=435473&TemplateId=1&rwndrnd=0.53516985889953&ActionFor=CDO&ExistApp=0&startMenu=no

Message: 'Telerik' is undefined
Line: 1841
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://DSM/Journal.aspx?AppId=379818&ClaimID=46944&IwID=48914&ClaimNo=0271068974&IwName=Angel Berrios&AppNo=380844&Screen=Appointment&hideTop=hide&ActId=435473&TemplateId=1&rwndrnd=0.53516985889953&ActionFor=CDO&ExistApp=0&startMenu=no

Message: 'Telerik' is undefined
Line: 969204706
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://DSM/Journal.aspx?AppId=379818&ClaimID=46944&IwID=48914&ClaimNo=0271068974&IwName=Angel Berrios&AppNo=380844&Screen=Appointment&hideTop=hide&ActId=435473&TemplateId=1&rwndrnd=0.53516985889953&ActionFor=CDO&ExistApp=0&startMenu=no

Message: '$telerik' is undefined
Line: 969204710
Char: 30
Code: 0
URI: http://DSM/Journal.aspx?AppId=379818&ClaimID=46944&IwID=48914&ClaimNo=0271068974&IwName=Angel Berrios&AppNo=380844&Screen=Appointment&hideTop=hide&ActId=435473&TemplateId=1&rwndrnd=0.53516985889953&ActionFor=CDO&ExistApp=0&startMenu=no

Message: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined
Line: 690414562
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://DSM/Appointment.aspx?c=Action&AId=377915&ActId=431329&CId=46567&hideTop=true&TemplateId=2&rwndrnd=0.597523773268164&IwName=Orbelicia Alvarez&ActionFor=CDO&ExistApp=0&startMenu=no
```

Comment: I found cause of issue and solution from link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126962#FixItForMeAlways --"Out of Memory" error message appears when you have a large number of programs running. We send solution to client, lets hope solution will works :)

Comment: I have several questions about this error report:  Javascript executes in the browser, not on the server.  If you are getting an Out of Memory error on the browser, then you are not having a problem with a server.  What does the HTML look like that you are trying to display in the browser?  I suspect that there is a memory leak in your javascript on the HTML page you are attempting to display.

Comment: yes you are right,this issue not related to server.Out of 100 employs,only some particular employs getting this issue. May be it is related to employee's system. May issue related to RAM? 
Page looks perfect but stops working when error comes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be things like you have an infinite loop, or something else wrong with the code that this can happen.  The $telerik/Telerik is undefined is a side-effect of the main problem, which is the out of memory error.  So we have to figure out why the ASPX page is triggering the out of memory.  I'd recommend shoving breakpoints everywhere to see if you can find an infinite loop, too many objects getting instantiated somewhere, or some other problem.

Comment: Hi Brian, you are right but we can't debug issue,main problem is we have checked application at our side using 3 to 4 different system but not able to reproduce ‘out of memory’.may be we have all 4 GB RAM systems.